# move var from javascript/jquery to php script on same page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pass JavaScript variables to PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917576/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-to-php)

how would I go about moving a javascript variable over to a php script without a form submission?

is it even possible?

ajax is an acceptable option but how

lets say I want to run thisnewoption.php    in process sending it javascript variable imgfilename which contains a string

Comment: Using [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) you can pass data from client to server.

Comment: (how with ajax - never done a thing with it) possible duplicate-it appears that is directed at submitting the form - or am I wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once your php page has loaded, there's no going back. The best way to go about passing variables ( data ) back to the server is with ajax, so it might be time to brush up on ajax http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Update: Tell you what, here is what a really basic ajax call looks like, notice that is send data to the server here with POST:

```
 $.ajax ( {type : 'POST' ,
    url : 'email.php' ,
    data : { variable: variable, anotherVariable: anotherVariable } ,
        success : function ( data ) { $('#some-div').html ( data ) ; }
    } ) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot literally pass a javascipt variable as a PHP one as PHP is evaluated on server side where as javascript on client. You can use ajax call to pass it however.